# Is it possible to spawn actors into stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

So i'm using Akka Typed, and want to spawn actor for each message into some stream, according documentation it seems not possible:

- *Warning*: This method is not thread-safe and must not be accessed from threads otherthan the ordinary actor message processing thread, such as [[scala.concurrent.Future]] callbacks.

`def spawn[U](behavior: Behavior[U], name: String, props: Props = Props.empty): ActorRef[U]`

Example:

```
  Behaviors.receiveMessage {
    case StartConsume =>
      context.log.info("Starting consume messages")
      val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 10)
      source.runForeach(x => context.spawn(Test(x), "Test"))
      Behaviors.same
  }
```

Are there some other ways to do this?

Comment: I am not sure "why" but you can absolutely create as many actors you want in your respective stream component. Just create your custom stream component using the graph component api and then do whatever you want inside of it. Also, why do you want to specifically use `spawn` to create your actors ? Why not create them the normal way ?

Comment: I'm new in akka typed, so how can i created actors instead of `spawn`?

Comment: From what I have seen, classic-actors play better with Akka streams. So, do you really need a typed-actor at that place ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the stream will materialize into a different actor, it's virtually certain that you can't close over an `ActorContext` in the stream (if it happens to execute in the same thread as the enclosing actor last ran on, it won't blow up), e.g for spawning a child.

As alternatives:

- If you don't particularly care that the spawned actors be children of this actor (e.g. in classic, you'd be using `system.actorOf`), you could have the guardian actor (the one with the behavior from spawning the `ActorSystem`) spawn the actors: you can either roll your own protocol to do such spawning or have that guardian implement `SpawnProtocol`.  You can then send the appropriate message to `context.system`, but note that you'll need to user `context.system.unsafeUpcast` to the protocol you're using.  Since you should have control over the guardian's protocol, that's unlikely to fail, but the compiler won't really help you.
- If you do want the spawned actors to be children, and you also want the spawns to be asynchronous, the best way to accomplish this is probably through an internal message that results in just spawning the actor.  Then in the stream you just send those messages to yourself.
- If you don't want the spawns to be asynchronous (which it should be noted, the approach of spawning them in a stream is), then just call `spawn` in the message processing thread without being in a stream.